# Windows Movie maker 2012 file transfer

Tags: google-drive, windows-movie-maker

Help,

I made a video on my computer at home with movie maker and I put it in Google Drive.
I downloaded the file from Google Drive but the video itself is missing.
The file is a .WLMP file

Can somebody help me on how I can get the video?

Comment: That doesn't work it says "Can not play the file. Possibly the player does not support the file type or the codec used to compress the file."...

Comment: My file is a .WLMP file so maybe that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you saved is a WLMP file.

This is a project file, not a file for playback in Windows Media Player (or similar).

You will need to convert it to the correct format.

Open the WLMP file in Windows Movie Maker (File -> Open).

Then File -> Save movie and export to a WMV video.